# More idiomatic version of "df.isnull().any().any()" w/ a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.isnull().any().any()
```

This line evaluates to a boolean True/False, as it checks whether a Pandas dataframe contains any NaN's in its rows or columns. Is there a more concise/idiomatic way of checking this?

Comment: `not df.notnull().all().all()` ;) But seriously your version looks fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53862445/11301900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's to use numpy's any:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, np.nan]])

In [12]: df.isnull().any().any()
Out[12]: True

In [13]: np.any(df.isnull())
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: This is much more intuitively readable :) thanks

Comment: @maxm ps. it's also faster/more efficient, as it's done in one pass with no temporaries.