# Elegant way to check if pandas dataframe contains any null items

Tags: python, pandas

To check if a dataframe like below contains any NaN's, I use the following code:

```
df.isnull().any().any()

mukey   hzdept_r    hzdepb_r    sandtotal_r silttotal_r
425897      0         61        
425897      61        152          5.3         44.7
425911      0         30           30.1        54.9
425911      30        74           17.7        49.8
425911      74        84
```

Is there a more elegant way to do the same?

Comment: I think that is a good way

Comment: How could anything possibly be more elegant?

Comment: I was thinking something like df.anynull()? Not complaining though, I love pandas!

Comment: Another way would be `df.dropna().shape == df.shape` or `df.dropna().equals(df)` but really there isn't much difference in terms of code length and readability

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318598/more-idiomatic-version-of-df-isnull-any-any-w-a-pandas-dataframe?rq=1